# Edge routing without crossing a vertex in mxgraph

Tags: mxgraph

I have a graph with vertices and edges (orthogonalEdgeStyle) and want to create new edges. After the creation the routing most times crosses existing vertices. Is there any possibility to route the new edges in a way that they not cross any vertex?
The best solution would be that other edges are also not crossed, but I think this is even more complex.
Any help is appreciated, if there is no build-in functionality (I found nothing), perhaps anybody has an idea where to start (overwrite function, algorithm)?

I'm also searching for a possibility to automatically create "bridges" if two edges are crossing.

Comment: There are two questions here, you should split the bridge question out.